# What is the error syntax mysql in eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse

```
String queryString = "select DISTINCT students.firstName, teacher.firstName, Course.title" + 
  " from Student,Faculty,Course ,(select Student.ssn, Student.firstName, Enrollment.courseId" + 
  "from Enrollment, Student" + 
  "where Enrollment.ssn = Student.ssn )as students," + 
  "(select Faculty.ssn, Faculty.firstName, TaughtBy.courseId" + 
  "from TaughtBy, Faculty where TaughtBy.ssn = Faculty.ssn )as teacher" +
  "where Student.ssn = ?  and Faculty.ssn = ? and students.courseId = teacher.courseId" ;
```

This sql query is working in sql server but doesn't work in mysql.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you have to meet spaces, try with a **space** after or before double quotes  for example:

```
String queryString = "select DISTINCT students.firstName, teacher.firstName, Course.title"+ " from Student,Faculty,Course ,(select Student.ssn, Student.firstName, Enrollment.courseId"+ " from Enrollment, Student"+" where Enrollment.ssn = Student.ssn )as students,"+" (select Faculty.ssn, Faculty.firstName, TaughtBy.courseId"+ " from TaughtBy, Faculty where TaughtBy.ssn = Faculty.ssn )as teacher"+ " where Student.ssn = ? and Faculty.ssn = ? and students.courseId = teacher.courseId" ;
```

Comment: the error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where TaughtBy.ssn = Faculty.ssn )as teacher where Student.ssn = '111221111' and' at line 1

Comment: there was another space problem that I corrected it. I just check it in the case of spaces